# use Javascript variable in SharePoint 2010 SQLDatasource Parameter Query no code behind

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I have a java script variable and I want to use it into my sqldatasource as a parameter how can I do this? Here is my java script code.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://icsid.worldbank.org/Style%20Library/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js"> type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var **userName** = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
 fieldName: "Name",//Name includes Domain userName DOES NOT
 

 debug: false
 });
 document.getElementById('UserID').innerHTML  = userName;
 });
 </script>

<asp:Label runat="server" id="UserID"></asp:Label>
```

I want to use var username as the @Sales_Pro_Number parameter in a SQL Query.
WHERE (([Customer Name] = @Customer_Name) AND ([Sales Pro Number] = @Sales_Pro_Number) AND ([Warehouse Id] = @Warehouse_Id)). Is there a way to store the var username and use it as the @Sales_Pro_Number parameter?
The below does not work.
**I cannot use code behind**

```html
<asp:SqlDataSource id="SqlDataSourceDropdownC_Done" runat="server" __designer:commandsync="true" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" ConnectionString=... 
SelectCommand="SELECT [Cust_Done] 
               FROM [sportsCD_Data_TEST] 
               WHERE (([Customer Name] = @Customer_Name) AND 
               ([Sales Pro Number] = @Sales_Pro_Number) AND 
               ([Warehouse Id] = @Warehouse_Id))" ....>
 <SelectParameters>
  <asp:controlparameter ControlID="DropDownListCustomer" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="Customer_Name" Type="String" />
  <asp:controlparameter ControlID="UserID" PropertyName="Text" Name="Sales_Pro_Number" Type="String" />
  <asp:controlparameter ControlID="DropDownListLocation" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="Warehouse_Id" Type="String" />
 </SelectParameters>
```

Or is there a way to extract SP user name and use as a parameter value?